# installing grub 2 on mdadm, which device?

Tags: grub2, raid, mdadm, software-raid

when installing grub(2) to mdadm devices are you supposed to install it to `/dev/sdX` or `/dev/mdX`?

Comment: This Q&A has some more information: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203279/where-to-install-grub/203289

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it on /dev/sdX devices because grub runs before you are able to know that that your are using raid devices. And you should install grub on all active disk that are part of the mdadm.